# How to assign passive easy-to-change styles to controls in VB.NET windows forms (similar to android styles.xml)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to add theme options to my VB.NET program **without** doing it the dirty way of repeating the same code for each element... Is it possible to create some styling method similar to what we have in android? (`styles.xml`)

First thing I started making is a library for the themes I want to use in my app but I quickly realized that it still won't help to use a regular class/group of methods since I will still have to call them everytime I need a control to be themed since it is not passive like the following:

```
Public Class Theme
    Public Shared Sub SetThemeLight(c As Control, Gray As Boolean)
        Dim LBack As Color = Color.White
        Dim LBackGray As Color = Color.WhiteSmoke
        Dim LFore As Color = SystemColors.ControlText
        Dim LForeGray As Color = Color.FromArgb(51, 51, 51)

        If Gray Then
            c.BackColor = LBackGray
            c.ForeColor = LForeGray
        Else
            c.BackColor = LBack
            c.ForeColor = LFore
        End If
    End Sub
'...

'Somewhere else in the program for example
Public Class Main
    Theme.SetThemeLight(TextBox1, False)
'...
```

Issue here is the excessive simplicity which is so inefficient. I would love to find an efficient way of theming similar to android's `styles.xml`

Comment: You can bind control properties in the designer.  Bind the appropriate colour properties of multiple controls to the same object property and then change that object property to change all the controls.  You can then populate the bound object from an XML file or wherever you want.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for the suggestion! but i quickly ran into a problem where i can change the value but it wouldn't apply (question is how do I update the control so it follows the new value in runtime?)

Comment: Binding requires properties with appropriate change events, so the bound control knows when the property values has changed so that it can update.  You can either have one event per property named after the property, e.g. property `Data` and event `DataChanged`, or you can implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.